# How to enable login button after user enter user name and password in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-architect, sencha-touch-2.1

Can anybody tell How to enable login button after user enter user name and password in sencha touch.initially login button is in disable state

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the button is disabled because its `disabled` config is set to `true`, e.g:

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    itemId: 'myButton',           
    disabled: true
}
```

you can enable it by calling `myButton.setDisabled(false)`.

You will need to get a reference to `myButton` and can do it through a [ComponentQuery](https://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.1.0/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery): `Ext.ComponentQuery.query('viewName button[itemId=myButton]')[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Use keypress event on your password field. Make sure you have to add this property for Password field. -- enableKeyEvents: true.

First get reference of your three fields UserName, Password and Login button in your controller file.
And add condition in keypress event like below:

```
if (userName.geValue() && passwordField.getValue()){
  loginButton.setDisabled(false);
} else {
   loginButton.setDisabled(true);
}
```